# Android camera capture session wrong aspect ratio

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2

I'm trying to display a preview of the camera on a SurfaceView, but I'm having trouble with the aspect ratio. The thing is that the aspect ratio of my camera is 4:3, so I set the surface's dimensions to meet this aspect ratio. But when the camera capture session starts displaying, the image is stretched. In fact, the image returned by the capture session is square, I don't know why, and that's why it is stretched on the SurfaceView, which is 4:3. Here are the important pieces of code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    try {
        mCameraIDsList = this.mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraIDsList[1]);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        Size size = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        ar = (float)size.getWidth()/size.getHeight();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    float w = mSurfaceView.getWidth();
    float h = mSurfaceView.getHeight();
    if(w * ar > h){
        holder.setFixedSize((int)(h/ar), (int)h);
    }
    else{
        holder.setFixedSize((int)w, (int)(w*ar));
    }
    mCameraSurface = holder.getSurface();
}

private class CaptureSessionListener extends
        CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback {

    @Override
    public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession session) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSessionConfigure onConfigured");
        mCaptureSession = session;

        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder previewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mCameraSurface);
            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                    null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setting up preview failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the image is square? And how do you force the image to be the first of the returned output sizes (`getOutputSizes()[0]`) ?

Comment: I know because if I set the SurfaceView dimensions to approximately the same measure it looks kinda good. Probably is not exactly square but kind of.
I do not force the image to be the first of the output sizes.

Comment: *I do not force the image to be the first of the output sizes* – this means that the actual 'capture' size may be anything. Often, you can see this size printed in logcat. You can try to use ImageReader (as an additional 'surface') and analyze the size of the image that you receive there.

Comment: Isn't there any easier way to know the capture size a priori?

Comment: I believe I understand what went wrong in your app. You should call [SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)) with one of the sizes returned by [StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)). But you only take the aspect ratio, and try to apply it to the size of **mSurfaceView**. If this size is not supported by your camera device, the result may look strange.

Comment: Tried it and didn't work. I finally solved it using CameraX.